# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un número a hexadecimal en Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

He intentado convertir el número que me devuelve una lectura a hexadecimal. No he encontrado referencia alguna.

Este es el código:

```
byte dummy = 0x00;

byte readCard[4];

String datoWifi = "";

 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  //
    readCard[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
        //dummy = (readCard[i], HEX); //esto no funciona
    datoWifi += (String) mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
    Serial.print(readCard[i], HEX);//de esta manera se imprime correctamente
  }
```

Usando `Serial.print(readCard[i], HEX);` se imprime el valor en hexadecimal perfectamente, sin embargo lo que necesito es poder construir `datoWifi` que es una variable de tipo `String` no con los números devueltos, sino con la conversión ya hecha.

Espero que exista alguna función ya creada para ello y que la solución no sea crear la función desde cero por que es lo que quiero evitar.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje? ¿[tag:c] o [tag:c++]?

Comment: Aquí (https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=257371.0) hablan del tema y creo que la solución es Serial.println(readCard[i], HEX);  pero en tu código ya hablas de Serial.print y no se si será lo mismo que Serial.println. En cualquier caso, hay otras respuestas, mira a ver...

Comment: Hola @track3r , gracias por el esfuerzo, la intención de lo que cuenta :). La función `Serial.print` envía su salida a través del puerto serie y lo que @Jorge desea es poder guardar ese valor que se envía correctamente por puerto serie en una variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es usar el [constructor de `String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) adecuado:

```
byte dummy = 0x00;

byte readCard[4];

String datoWifi = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    readCard[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
    datoWifi += String(readCard[i], HEX);
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, elijo esta respuesta por la efectividad y simplicidad ya que es lo que necesito. mil gracias

Answer (score 2):

Para este tipo de conversiones tienes la librería `iomanip` (IO MANIPulation). Lo que sucede es que esta librería solo trabaja con *streams*. Así que la solución pasa por usar `stringstream` y, posteriormente, volcar el resultado a tu variable `string`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << mrfc522.uid.uidByte[i];
datoWifi += ss.str();
```

Si necesitas el `0x` típico de los números en hexadecimal, tendrás que añadirlo manualmente:

```
ss << "0x" << std::hex << mrfc522.uid.uidByte[i];
```

Comment: También ha funcionado perfectamente. una solución muy interesante del lado de 'c' puro y duro . mil gracias.

Comment: @Jorge no es C sino C++. En C esto no compila... para tu fortuna estás compilando arduino con C++

Comment: Ok, mil gracias de todas maneras.